# How to force a user logout in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

In my Django app under certain conditions I want to be able to force users to log out by a username. Not necessarily the current user who is logged in, but another user. So, the request method in my view doesn't have any session information about the user that I want to logout.

I am familiar with django.auth and with auth. logout method, but it takes *request* as an argument. Is there a "Django-way" to log the user out if all I have is the username? Or do I have to roll my own logout SQL?

Comment: Why do you want to logout an user other than the user who loggedin ? if you are using Browser-length sessions those users who are not loggedin are already loggedout.

Comment: Let's say that I need to logout the user when the password has been changed. I've got over 100k users and around 140k sessions in the session table. How to handle this efficiently?

Comment: @kjagiello Take a look at https://github.com/QueraTeam/django-qsessions backend. Using it, you can easily logout a user: `user.session_set.all().delete()`. Disclaimer: I'm the author of django-qsessions.

Answer (score 97):

Update:

Since Django 1.7, users are automatically logged-out when their password changes. On each request, the current password hash is compared to the value saved in their session and if doesn't match, the user is logged-out.

So, a simple password update has the effect of logging the user out. You can then disable the account for login, or advise them to use the password reset feature to set a new password and log in again.

Original:

I don't think there is a sanctioned way to do this in Django yet.

The user id is stored in the session object, but it is encoded. Unfortunately, that means you'll have to iterate through all sessions, decode and compare...

Two steps:

First delete the session objects for your target user. If they log in from multiple computers they will have multiple session objects.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# grab the user in question 
user = User.objects.get(username='johndoe')

[s.delete() for s in Session.objects.all() if s.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id') == user.id]
```

Then, if you need to, lock them out....

```
user.is_active = False
user.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this seams rather brute force solution, the one I was trying to avoid. However if there are no other options I might have to go with it, probably with a small improvement instead of getting "all" sessions get the ones that were updated within last "x" minutes, hopefully that would drastically improve the perfomance.

Comment: No prob. Filtering the session data on last updated would be a worthwhile improvement.

Comment: Worth noting that Django 1.7 supports [session invalidation on password change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change).

Comment: For django 1.8.2, last string need some change (convert both elements to str ), as: [s.delete() for s in Session.objects.all() if str(s.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')) == str(user.id)]

Comment: @DavidM's URL is now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change

Comment: Will this delete the session cookie in the users browser? If not, wouldn't this cookie cause the SuspiciousOperation exception with each attempt to access the web?

Comment: All session objects are deleted but the user is still logged in.. i want to forcefully log out all users of my site. is any other needed to be done?

Answer (score 69):

Although Harold's answer works in this specific case, I can see at least two important issues with it:

1. This solution can only be used with a database [session engine](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine). In other situations (cache, file, cookie) the `Session` model would not be used.
2. When the number of sessions and users in database grows, this becomes quite inefficient.

To solve those issues, I suggest you take another approach at the problem. The idea is to store somewhere the date when the user was logged in for a given session, and the last time you requested a user to be logged out.

Then whenever someone access your site, if the logged in date is **lower than** the log out date, you can force-logout the user. As dan said, there's no practical difference between logging out a user immediately or on his next request to your site.

Now, let's see a possible implementation of this solution, for **django 1.3b1**. In three steps:

#### 1. store in the session the last login date

Fortunately, Django auth system exposes a [signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/signals/) called `user_logged_in`. You just have to register that signals, and save the current date in the session. At the bottom of your `models.py` :

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from datetime import datetime

def update_session_last_login(sender, user=user, request=request, **kwargs):
    if request:
        request.session['LAST_LOGIN_DATE'] = datetime.now()
user_logged_in.connect(update_session_last_login)
```

#### 2. request a force logout for a user

We just need to add a field and a method to the `User` model. There's multiple ways to achieve that ([user profiles](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users), [model inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), etc.) each with pros and cons.

For the sake of simplicity, I'm gonna use model inheritance here, if you go for this solution, don't forget to [write a custom authentication backend](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/).

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class MyUser(User):
    force_logout_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def force_logout(self):
        self.force_logout_date = datetime.now()
        self.save()
```

Then, if you want to force logout for user `johndoe`, you just have to:

```
from myapp.models import MyUser
MyUser.objects.get(username='johndoe').force_logout()
```

#### 3. implement the check on access

Best way here is to use a [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/middleware/#middleware) as dan suggested. This middleware will access `request.user`, so you need to put it **after** `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class ForceLogoutMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.force_logout_date and \
           request.session['LAST_LOGIN_DATE'] < request.user.force_logout_date:
            logout(request)
```

That should do it.

---

**Notes**

- Be aware of the performance implication of storing an extra field for your users. Using model inheritance will add an extra `JOIN`. Using user profiles will add an extra query. Modifying directly the `User` is the best way performance wise, but it is still a [hairy topic](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3011).
- If you deploy that solution on an existing site, you will probably have some trouble with existing sessions, which won't have the `'LAST_LOGIN_DATE'` key. You can adapt a bit the middleware code to deal with that case :

  ```
   from django.contrib.auth import logout

   class ForceLogoutMiddleware(object):
       def process_request(self, request):
           if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.force_logout_date and \
              ( 'LAST_LOGIN_DATE' not in request.session or \
                request.session['LAST_LOGIN_DATE'] < request.user.force_logout_date ):
               logout(request)
  ```
- In django 1.2.x, there is no `user_logged_in` signal. Fall back to overriding the `login` function:

  ```
   from django.contrib.auth import login as dj_login
   from datetime import datetime

   def login(request, user):
       dj_login(request, user)
       request.session['LAST_LOGIN_DATE'] = datetime.now()
  ```

Comment: I'm a novice, so please excuse me if i misunderstand, but shouldn't it be:  update_session_last_login(sender, user='user', request='request', **kwargs):?

Comment: Actually, I think Clément meant: def update_session_last_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):.

Answer (score 52):

I needed something similar in my app. In my case, if a user was set to inactive, I wanted to make sure if the user was already logged in that they will be logged out and not able to continue to use the site. After reading this post, I came to the following solution:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class ActiveUserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return
        if not request.user.is_active:
           logout(request)
```

Just add this middleware in your settings and off you go. In the case of changing passwords, you could introduce a new field in the userprofile model that forces a user to logout, check for the value of the field instead of is_active above, and also unset the field when a user logs in. The latter can be done with Django's [user_logged_in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#login-and-logout-signals) signal.

Comment: Using the changed password field mentioned. If you are logged in on 2 locations and you change your password at A, then log in at A. The changed password flag would be unset and you would remain logged in at B, without having to enter the new password.

Comment: @Mark, you are absolutely correct. I've hit this problem when using WebSockets. The solution was I adapted there was to manage storing the connections by myself so I could manipulate them. Sounds like a similar approach would be required here, i.e., another session table that maps users to session ids.

Comment: Your solution was exactly what I had in mind before searching for other ways, and I finally did it like this after landing on this page. Just one comment: your condition could be wrote like this to be (in my opinion) clearer: `if request.user.is_authenticated() and not request.user.is_active`

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps, a bit of middleware that references a list of users who have been forced to log out. Next time the user tries to do anything, log them out then, redirects them, etc.

Unless of course, they need to be logged out immediately. But then again, they wouldn't notice until they next tried to make a request anyway, so the above solution may just work.

Answer (score 6):

This is in response to Balon's query:

Yes, with around 140k sessions to iterate through I can see why Harold's answer may not be as fast as you may like!

The way I would recommend is to add a model whose only two properties are foreign keys to `User` and `Session` objects. Then add some middleware that keeps this model up-to-date with current user sessions. I have used this sort of setup before; in my case, I borrowed the `sessionprofile` module from this [Single Sign-On system for phpBB](http://code.google.com/p/django-login-for-phpbb/) (see the source code in the "django/sessionprofile" folder) and this (I think) would suit your needs.

What you would end up with is some management function somewhere in your code like this (assuming the same code names and layout as in the `sessionprofile` module linked above):

```
from sessionprofile.models import SessionProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Find all SessionProfile objects corresponding to a given username
sessionProfiles = SessionProfile.objects.filter(user__username__exact='johndoe')

# Delete all corresponding sessions
[sp.session.delete() for sp in sessionProfiles]
```

(I think this will also delete the `SessionProfile` objects, as from what I recall, Django's default behaviour when an object referenced by a `ForeignKey` is deleted is to cascade it and also delete the object containing the `ForeignKey`, but if not then it is trivial enough to delete the contents of `sessionProfiles` when you are done.)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use direct django function to do that, it will update and logs out all other sessions for the user, except the current one.

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
update_session_auth_hash(self.request, user)
```

Docs for update_session_auth_hash [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.update_session_auth_hash).

Answer (score 2):

As Tony Abou-Assaleh, I also needed to log out users who were set to inactive, so I started by implementing his solution. After some time I found out that the middleware is forcing a DB query on all requests (to check if the user was blocked), and thus hurts performance on pages that doesn't require login.

I have a custom user object and Django >= 1.7, so what I ended up doing is overriding its [`get_session_auth_hash`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.get_session_auth_hash) function to invalidate the session when the user is inactive. A possible implementation is:

```
def get_session_auth_hash(self):
    if not self.is_active:
        return "inactive"
    return super(MyCustomUser, self).get_session_auth_hash()
```

For this to work, `django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` should be in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, you can iterate over *all* sessions in DB, decode all of them, and delete those belonging to that user. But it's slow, particularly if your site has high traffic and there are lots of sessions.

If you need a faster solution, you can use a session backend that lets you query and get the sessions of a specific user. In these session backends, Session has a foreign key to User, so you don't need to iterate over *all* session objects:

- [django-qsessions](https://github.com/QueraTeam/django-qsessions) (based on django's `db`, `cached_db` session backends)
- [django-user-sessions](https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions) (based on django's `db` session backend)

Using these backends, deleting all sessions of a user can be done in a single line of code:

```py
user.session_set.all().delete()
```

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of `django-qsessions`.

Answer (score 0):

from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

## deleting user session

```
[s.delete() for s in Session.objects.all() if s.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_hash') == user.get_session_auth_hash()]
```

Answer (score -5):

Even I faced this issue. Few spammers from India keep posting about those Baba and Molvi for love solutions.

What I did is at the time of posting just inserted this code:

```
if request.user.is_active==False:
            return HttpResponse('You are banned on the site for spaming.')
```

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question. He is not asking for a means to deny response to a deleted user