# How can i kick off a user who has logged-in in django?

Tags: django

I am using Django.

How can i kick off a user who has logged-in?

or

How can i get the user's session and kill it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953879/how-to-force-user-logout-in-django ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can access the shell, then:

```
$ ./manage.py shell

In [1]: from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

In [2]: for s in Session.objects.all():
   ...:     data = s.get_decoded()
   ...:     if data.get('_auth_user_id', None) == YOUR_USER_ID:
   ...:         s.delete()
   ...:         
   ...:
```

Replace `YOUR_USER_ID` with the ID of a user to be kicked.

The key `'_auth_user_id'` may differ from version to version, I suppose, but that worked for me. To check if you have the same, just print out some of `s.get_decoded()` and look at the output.

Comment: Oh, haven't noticed the comment from John…