# Terminating Session using Apache and Django

Tags: django, apache, module

On a system I have developed It requires me to login using a standard and simple username and password combination.

The system I use is Django does anyone know how I can kill this session so that when a user presses log off it invokes the login screen again.

Cheers,

Comment: Seems to me like you need to redirect your view when logging out, anyway: if you use django-auth system, the session is killed when you logoff the user.

Comment: Duplicate?  Good answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953879/how-to-force-user-logout-in-django/954318#954318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default authentication system `django.contrib.auth`, you simply need to create a view that calls [`django.contrib.auth.logout()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.logout) and wire a url to it.

Luckily, the `auth` [app already has a view that does this](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L73), so you simply need to redirect the user to

```
/logout/
```