# django sanction oauth2.0 logging out user

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to integrate [django sanction](https://github.com/demianbrecht/django-sanction) into my blog app (django newbie here), but I seem not to be able to "logout" the user after the login process (using Google OAuth2.0).

The entire process seems pain free - i.e I am able to get all user details on my db, and able to access user details on my django templates, but, when I logout and try to log back in, it seems to remember my credentials (cookies?). I am trying to logout from [here](https://github.com/demianbrecht/django-sanction/blob/master/example/example/templates/profile.html)

p.s: I am developing on localhost - wondering if this is the problem(?)

Comment: What does view your /o/logout/ serve up?

Comment: It would be useful to see your view.

Comment: @GordonsBeard: /o/logout/ goes back to localhost:8000 but when I try to login again, it shows the same google profile info - which indicates it has not logged me out.

Comment: @GlynJackson: views.py is on: https://github.com/demianbrecht/django-sanction/blob/master/example/example/views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [How to force user logout in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953879/how-to-force-user-logout-in-django)

quote:

```
I don't think there is a sanctioned way to do this in Django yet.

The user id is stored in the session object, but it is encoded. Unfortunately, that means you'll have to iterate through all sessions, decode and compare...
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe :(