# Is it safe to add user_id column to Django db session model?

Tags: python, django

Currently the Django session model doesn't have an user ID field:

```py
class AbstractBaseSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(_('session key'), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    session_data = models.TextField(_('session data'))
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(_('expire date'), db_index=True)
```

This is impossible for us to implement "back-channel logout" because every service provider would have different session ids. To make this work, I will need to add an user identification field to the model, eg. `username`, so that the IdP can issue log out signal to all service providers to log the user out by using the `username`

```py
class AbstractBaseSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(_('session key'), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    session_data = models.TextField(_('session data'))
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(_('expire date'), db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(...)
```

I am not 200% sure if this will have any security implications? Thought I'd post here to check with the experts.

Comment: you would not do this ... all those keys are part of the data payload which is just an arbitrary key,value store  ... try something like `request.session["username"]="test@email.com"`  then print the get decoded stuff ... I would not recommend implementing your own session stuff ... but you could i guess

Comment: @JoranBeasley sorry I don't get what you said, the back-channel log out would not involve a request object. BTW I removed the `get_decoded()` part out of the question as it's unrelated

Comment: its not unrelated it is very related ... all that stuff that was printed is encoded in the `session_data` ... so when the user logs in you simply add their username to the request.session ... then when you go to do your logout the decoded_data will contain whatever info you added to the request.session

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think you misunderstood my question. I want to implement 'back-channel' logout without using session id to identify an user session record in db, but use an user id to get the session records in db to delete them.

Comment: ok... then i guess you would need to alter the table ... and anywhere that writes to the table ... still seems dicey ...

Comment: yeah hence asked the question here as I am not 100% sure if this is totally secured in the sense of cyber security

Comment: just as secured as any other db table i imagine ... might violate some gdpr stuff as email counts as PII

Comment: So far I haven't found any implementation like this so this has me worried about there would be a reason for it.

Comment: this seems simillar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617751/how-to-make-a-django-user-inactive-and-invalidate-all-their-sessions

Comment: in fact it looks like django recommends this practice http://www.matrix.umcs.lublin.pl/DOC/python-django-doc/html/topics/http/sessions.html#example

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks, qsession looks like just what I am after